# Magento files: where to paste and read results of this query

Tags: magento

I am giving up on trying to fetch values for all product attributes on magento by SQL as it gets a nightmare of joins, yet, I am not familiar with the folders structure and I dont know where to paste this query below. Could anyone give me a handguided enumeration on where to go please? If possible I d like to have more values, like description, meta keywords etc

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

echo '<table border="1"> ';
echo '<tr>';
echo "<th>entity_id <th />";
echo "<th>store_id <th />";
echo "<th>name<th />";
echo "<th>sku <th />";
echo "<th>price<th />";
echo "<th>status<th />";
echo '</tr>';

foreach ($collection as $product_all) {
  $sku = $product_all['sku'];
  $product_id =  $product_all['entity_id'];
  // call product model and create product object
  $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

  $pk_sku = $product['sku'];
  $pk_name = $product['name'];
  $store_id = $product->getStoreIds();
  $pk_price = $product['price'];
  $status = $product->getStatus();

  echo '<tr>';
  echo "<td>".$product_id."<td />";
  echo "<td>".$store_id[0]."<td />";
  echo "<td>".$pk_name."<td />";
  echo "<td>".$pk_sku."<td />";
  echo "<td>".$pk_price."<td />";
  echo "<td>".$status."<td />";
  echo '</tr>'; 
 }
echo '</table>';?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see product attribute data, these are the tables in the db you need to concern yourself with.

`catalog_product_entity`: stores all base product data

`eav_attribute`: lists all attribute_codes and the attribute type

`catalog_product_entity_{varchar/int/datetime/..}`: contains relevant attribute values based on eav_attribute `attribute_id` and catalog_product_entity `entity_id`.

So if you wanted to use a SQL query to get a certain attribute, you could use a statement like this to view all varchar attributes stored for a particular product (or all products):

```
SELECT cpe.entity_id, cpe.sku,  attrib.attribute_id, attrib.value
FROM catalog_product_entity AS cpe
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT entity_id, attribute_id, VALUE
    FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar AS attrib
) AS attrib ON cpe.entity_id = attrib.entity_id
WHERE cpe.sku = '{your sku here}';
```

With these tables and a little more research into the eav system and a little sql knowledge, you should be able to wrap your head around how the system works and see the data you need.

Comment: I think you left out writing AS attrib to add the alias for the other table but I get your point. Thank you.